# $.post() doesn't work if there's a re-direct after it: window.location.href =

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list and when an element from that list is clicked I want to record some info in my database so I'm using the following:

```
<li class="item"><a href="javascript:addactivity()">Add activity</a></li>

<script>
function addactivity(){

    $.post('update.php');   
    window.location.href = "http://www.mysite.com/page.php";

}
</script>
```

If I comment out window.location.href = "http://www.mysite.com/page.php"; the database is updated because $.post('update.php'); works properly.  If I don't comment out window.location.href = "http://www.mysite.com/page.php"; the database is not updated but the re-direct works to www.mysite.com.

For some reason adding window.location.href = "http://www.mysite.com/page.php"; stops       $.post('update.php'); from running.  Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: Use the success callback for $.post. Check out [jQuery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the callbacks to manage the situation:

```
function onSuccess() {
  window.location.href = "http://www.mysite.com/page.php";
}

function onFailure() {
  alert('An error has ocurred while updating database');
}

$.post('update.php').done(onSuccess).fail(onFailure);
```

Read in [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) others examples, and why it works:

> As of jQuery 1.5, all of jQuery's Ajax methods return a superset of
>   the XMLHTTPRequest object. This jQuery XHR object, or "jqXHR,"
>   returned by $.get() implements the Promise interface, giving it all
>   the properties, methods, and behavior of a Promise (see Deferred
>   object for more information). The jqXHR.done() (for success),
>   jqXHR.fail() (for error), and jqXHR.always() (for completion, whether
>   success or error) methods take a function argument that is called when
>   the request terminates.

This talks about $.get, but the same works for $.post.

Answer (score 0):

Use the success method that will wait until the post completes before it does a redirect

```
$.post('update.php', function(){
    window.location.href = "http://www.mysite.com/page.php";
});
```